# MSCaptcha don't work in SubFolder in Integrated MVC And Webform Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, webforms

I have a project that Integrated MVC and Webform. MScaptch work fine in aspx in root but do not work in the aspx files that are in the internal folders.

faq.aspx---> in root ----Mscaptcha is ok.

**BranchPortal/Faq.aspx ---> Mscaptcha dont work here.**

My Web.config Code:

```
<system.web>    
<httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" />
      <add verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler,MSCaptcha"/>
.
.
.
.
<system.webServer>
<handlers >
      <remove name="CAPTCHAHandler" />
      <add name="CAPTCHAHandler" verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler,MSCaptcha" />
```

mscaptch has rendered in aspx files in subfolders  as below :

http://localhost:4966/BranchPortal/CaptchaImage.axd?guid=fe88a632-3832-4a7f-9c1d-c749ecc658f4  ----->    Error: 404 (Not Found)

in root is ok

http://localhost:4966/CaptchaImage.axd?guid=fe88a632-3832-4a7f-9c1d-c749ecc658f4

sorry for poor english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by adding this line:

**routes.IgnoreRoute("BranchPortal/{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("BranchPortal/{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```